# Validation causes lost in values

Tags: spring, jsf, primefaces, spring-webflow

I am using spring web flow 2.4.0 and primefaces 5.0. I found that when there is a failure in front end primefaces validation, e.g. number format. It will trigger some correct values lost in the same form id. It has not trigger any function in the web flow and I have not assigned null values to these correct values.

I have been tried to solve but failed. Do you have any hints or solutions??
Please help.

Note: It happened in `selectmanycheckbox` with `selectedvalue` that the `itemsdisable` is true.

Comment: i do not have idea about spring, but i am sure if any validation fall on page it will not hit back bean, if all validation pass that it hit bean, when user click on button. can you post some code?

Comment: Please clarify your question and put code sample  so we can understand. Otherwise the question will be downvoted and deleted.

Comment: <p:panelGrid columns="1" >
    <p:selectManyCheckbox layout="grid" id="gridTeacherName"  value="#{teacherList.selectTeachers.selectedValue}" >
           <f:selectItems itemLabelEscaped="false" value="#{teacherList.selectTeachers.filterTeacherNameList}" var="teacher" itemDisabled="#{teacherList.selectTeachers.disableCheckBox(teacher.timRefNo)}" itemLabel="#{teacher.getisServingMoreThanOneSchool()}" itemValue="#{teacher.timRefNo}" />
    </p:selectManyCheckbox>
   </p:panelGrid>

Comment: If I remove itemDisabled.... attribute, it will not have problem But the checkbox is enabled.